# .net core console app implement persistent cache

Tags: c#, caching, .net-core

**Tools**

- Visual Studio 2017 v15.8.7
- dotnet core sdk v2.1.403

**Scenario**

I'm trying to implement a persistent cache that stores responses from api calls.  It's important that this cache is available between application runs.  I've been looking at [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.1#using-imemorycache) to understand how in-memory caching works in dotnet core.

However, since it's an in-memory cache it only caches the data on a per application run basis.

**Question**

How can a cache be implemented so that it persists even after the application has run?  Where should the cached information reside?  In a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to create an application which is responsible for caching. If this new application will always run, then your idea of persistency is fulfilled. As about storing the cache for the case when the caching application has stopped working you can use a database, like Redis.